# Save data for offline webapp Firestore

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, indexeddb

I am trying to create a PWA with firestore back-end. I am not sure if there is need to retain user's data in an indexedDB database or the firebase will do the job.

If you recommend using  indexedDB would you please point out to any existing solution for synchronizing the database after re-connection from offline.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you enable offline data for Cloud Firestore, it will use indexedDB in the background to cache the data. This feature is still officially experimental, but it does work, and is much easier than writing your own indexedDB cache from scratch.

Full details here:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/enable-offline